# Ruby on rails - how to update my rails database (MYSQL) with values from csv file on a daily basis?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, excel

I have a csv file which contains very detailed data of the products that my company sells and it gets updated daily.

And I want my rails to import the data from the csv file then update my database (MYSQL) if there are any new changes found.

What's the best way to achieve this? Some people mentioned about MYSQL for excel. Would this be the way to go about it?

I will appreciate if someone can give me a guidance on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not gonna walk through the details, specifically because you have no details, nothing attempted at all so I'm gonna stick with a overview.

From a systems point of view I would (assuming your rails app is live and not local):

- have the CSV file live in place where you (or whoever needs to) can update it and is also fetchable to the application (dropbox, s3 bucket, your own server, wtv).
- have a daily cron rake task, that downloads the CSV file
- parse the CSV file and decide what to update.

The trickiest part will be to decide what to update from the CSV and it will depend on how it can change itself. Like if only new lines can be added, or lines removed, if columns in lines can be changed, etc.

Comment: Great. First time hearing about Cron. Thanks for the quick advice. I will dive into it tonight then go from there.